# REACT Check the render method of `Route`. helpme T.T

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGJ3k.png)

This Image is Error Image

I am making react spa but i cannot figure this error! T.T

help me!

I think this error is begun in App.js
But I don't know what should I do...

This is index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.scss';
import App from './containers/App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

This is App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as classNames from 'classnames/bind';
import styles from './App.scss';

import Main from './Main/Main'

const cx = classNames.bind(styles);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={cx("App")}>
        <nav>
            <div><Link to="/">JUMP</Link></div>
        </nav>
       <main>
           <div className={cx("main")}>
               <Switch>
                   <Route path="/" exact component={Main}/>
               </Switch>
           </div>
       </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is folder structure

```
├── src
│   ├── components
│   │   └── Headers
│   ├── containers
│   │   ├── 0.Login
│   │   │   ├──Login.js
│   │   │   └──Login.sass
│   │   ├── App.scss
│   │   ├── App.js
│   ├── index.scss
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── logo.scv
└── └── serviceWorker.js
```

Comment: That error link is picture about error

Comment: Kindly add your code here, and what have you tried so far.

Comment: @Fawzi I added it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error mentions you probably mixed up default export with named export. 
Check the import line for `Main`, depending on the way you exported it, you might have to change the way you imported it.

Comment: oh I figured!! Thanks a lot :):) XD

Answer (score 0):

I see you import Main component in App.js file. But I don't see the main file in the structure. Please double check the export in Main component.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same error in my browser but I solved this in App.js by changing the import

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

to

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

You also have to define your route like this in App.js

```
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
  
    <Route exact path="/home" component={ HomePage } />
    <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={ Dashboard } />
    <Route exact path="/login" component={ loginPage } />
    <Route exact path="/register" component={ registerPage } />
    <Route exact path="/profile" component={ profilePage } />

    </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

You are probably running react-router 5
With React 17
I am using these dependencies

```
 "react": "17",
"react-bootstrap": "^2.7.4",
"react-dom": "17",
"react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
```